# When using Stripe as your payment gateway, will a user's trial period restart if they change the plan they are on?

Tags: stripe-payments, subscription, period, trial

Currently our Trial Period is being handled in the back-end of our application and not handled by Stripe. Our devs are telling us this is because the Trial period can be abused by users by changing their subscription plan just before their trial runs out which allows them to restart their plan.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your backend. At the beginning of the very first trial, the user can be marked by a "tiral_used" (or whatever) boolean field. Thus, even if they change their plan right before the end of the trial, your backend will check if this user has used the trial or not and it won't start another trial again.

Stripe handles the trial pretty good also.